# exporting function vs const then export

Tags: node.js, design-patterns

I'm a NOOB to NodeJs and trying to understand the difference and pros and cons to  a couple of patterns ....

In a controller I often see people use :

```
exports.myFunction = async function (req, res) { ......}
```

In other examples I see

```
const myFunction = async function (req, res) { ......}
module.exports = {myfunction}
```

1. what is the advantage of declaring the function as constant then exporting it vs exporting it as part of the definition? Is it just style, or will it make the code more testable or something else?
2. I have seen that people code services as classes and export the whole class.  Is this best practice?
3. Why not define controllers as classes, and why not export the class?

I see these patterns mixed up in various articles talking about patterns and practices and haven't got my head around the nuances.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest reason to define the function beforehand is to allow it to be referenced later more easily. This:

```
const myFunction = (arg) => console.log(arg);

myFunction('foo');

module.exports = { myFunction };
```

is what some might prefer to

```
module.exports.myFunction = (arg) => console.log(arg);

module.exports.myFunction('foo');
```

especially if the function needs to be referenced multiple times.

> Is this best practice?

It's completely opinion-based. Some like it, others don't.

> Why not define controllers as classes

JavaScript isn't like Java - there's absolutely nothing wrong with passing plain functions around and using them, without having to construct a class to surround them. Often, using plain functions without classes *just works*, and putting them in a class would only add extra syntactical noise without providing any benefit.

The main reason to use a class is when you want to associate *persistent data* with *methods that can operate on the data*. If you have only data, a plain object (or array) often does the trick; if you only want to operate on data without storing it in another container, a plain function often does the trick.

But that's not a hard and fast rule. If preferred, you can still use classes wherever you want anyway - you can also omit classes entirely and use only functions/objects. Any logic that can be accomplished with a class can also be accomplished without it, and vice versa.

Comment: thanks. that makes sense. I can't think of a reason why I would call a controller method from somewhere else, unless  I had encapsulated some business logic in it that should probably sit in a service. In which case, personally I think putting the Exports in the function definition is a little easier to maintain.

services are perhaps a better case for classes as they will encapsulate internal and external logic and states.